# If I allow users to write HTML for their "profile", what elements should I disallow/remove to keep it safe for other users?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For my users' profiles, I am going to let them insert HTML code, which will be displayed on their profile.

Is there any special tags I need to manually remove when they save their profile?

Besides the `<script>` tag, what else could be dangerous?

What else could be "dangerous"?

Comment: What if you take the point of view of not allowing any tags and then think about what to allow / what people would perhaps need? Wow.. didn't read the question properly.. _Manually remove_? ..wow..

Comment: @Lollero Ok, manually remove LOL

Comment: manually remove = using code...not with my fingers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

applet, embed, object, script and iframe should be avoided at all costs.

a and img can be problematic as they allow linking to off-site resources. They can also contain javascript: urls

Avoid letting users enter any head-tags into cotnent meant for the body.  style, link, meta, title etc

You also have to be careful of attributes.  Don't allow any attribute that begins with on, as they are javascript event bindings.  You also want to check any URL attributes for javascript: and data: urls.

**EDITED TO ADD**:

Forms and their children are also probably something to avoid as they can be used to dupe users into entering information that gets harvested by some other site.

I'd recommend using a whitelisting policy instead of blacklisting when it comes to tags and attributes, as it's far easier to miss something with a blacklist.  Also with HTML5 gaining traction there's a whole host of new tags and attributes to watch out for.

Comment: off-topic: If I wrap all of this custom HTML inside an Iframe and display it, would it be "safer" ?

Comment: I don't think that would be entirely safe, besides, if the included content doesn't match the iframe size (and you can't easily make them size automatically to the content) you'll get scroll bars.  Also they can mess browser history navigation up.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much everything. You don't know that people aren't doing:

```
<img onload="hax" />
```

In addition, you MUST validate it server-side, not just client-side

Answer (score 2):

`img` seems another obvious one. But I agree with Lollero, don't think in terms of what to disallow, but in terms of what to *allow*. And keep in mind that it's not just tags, but attributes as well. You want to build a whitelist of tags and the attributes you want to allow on them.

FWIW, here's the whitelist that Wordpress uses for comments by default (er, at least the fairly out-of-date install of it I have handy):

- `a`

  - `href` - be sure to only allow the protocols you want to allow, e.g., probably not the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol.
  - `title`
- `abbr`

  - `title`
- `acronym`

  - `title`
- `b`
- `blockquote`

  - `cite`
- `cite`
- `code`
- `del`

  - `datetime`
- `em`
- `i`
- `q`

  - `cite`
- `strike`
- `strong`

(You can find this list in the `$allowedTags` variable in `wp-includes/kses.php`.) I figured it was relevant as Wordpress is a hugely popular platform.

Comment: @user847495: It's up to you, just be aware that allowing `img` means people can put **any** picture on your website. There's nothing to stop them embedding a 2,000x2,000 picture of [insert something inappropriate and/or gross here], completely blowing your layout. Or the more subtle ones, animated gifs that look innocuous for the first 10 seconds or so and then switch to [insert...here]. Or even something someone thinks is fine, but suddenly you're getting outraged email from people who *don't* think Calvin having a wee is appropriate for your site. (Can you tell I've been there?)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: That kind of abuse is certainly a problem, but it is also open to far more insidious abuse by having the image tag link to what is actually a script that can record user details, harvest cookies and so on whilst displaying what appears to be a perfectly innocent image.  In addition to tag and attrib blocking some sort of URL vetting is probably also in order, restricting allowed URLs to a whitelist of trusted sites.

Comment: @GordonM: Not a bad idea at all.

Answer (score 2):

Basically **remove every tag and attribute** *except* **harmless** ones you want to allow like, `p`, `strong`, `b`, `em`, `ul`, `ol`, `li`, `div`, `span`, `h2`, `h3`, `u`, `i`

If you allow `img` tag, make sure not to remove `alt`, `src` and `title` attribute.

If you allow `a` tag, make sure not to remove `href` attribute.

Consider this, the list of possible tags and attributes will be almost *endless* in your check code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're not using PHP or other server-side processing, the only other elements I'd worry about are `iframe, object, and applet`

If you are using a server-side language, just make sure to also sanitize any user input.

You might also want to read up on XSS attacks, just to be wary of any malicious crap: http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Answer (score 1):

http://html5sec.org/ is a good list of what can be used to execute Javascript.

The best approach is to use whitelist: remove everything except what's definitely safe, like few basic styling elements; don't allow any attributes, if possible.